# Java Input mismatch exception basic

Tags: java

[This is the program that I ran. After running this I came across the error message that I also posted but I don't know what I did wrong! Please help!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrXWU.png)

[This is the error message that came up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZZ93.png)

Comment: Please always include your code, comments, and pictures within your post so that users aren't forced to leave the site to answer your question.

Comment: It restricted me from doing so b/c I'm a new member

Comment: You can put in code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are likely entering in "JPY 10000", and since the "JPY" part is a `String` rather than a `double`, if you try to store it in your `double JPY` it will result in a type mismatch error.

Please double check if the requirement is only to enter "10000", or the whole "JPY 100000" thing. If it is to enter the whole thing, try the code below:

```
String[] jpy = stdin.nextLine().split(" "); // split the input with a space
double JPY = Double.parseDouble(jpy[1]); // parse the second part of input as double

String[] eur = stdin.nextLine().split(" ");
double EUR= Double.parseDouble(eur[1]);
// and so on...

double USD = JPY/100) + EUR/0.9 + ...;
```

This code is vulnerable and you should really check for malformed inputs. But it is the general idea of how you should approach this.

Comment: I am just supposed to make the program so that any input value can be placed in the "10000" thing is just an example of what the computer can enter

Comment: yes it says its missing a symbol in the .split(" "); part

Comment: Problem.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    String[] jpy = stdin.nextLine().split(); 
                   ^
  symbol:   variable stdin
  location: class Problem
Problem.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
String[] eur = stdin.nextLine().split();
               ^
  symbol:   variable stdin
  location: class Problem
Problem.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
String[] cad = stdin.nextLine().split();
               ^
  symbol:   variable stdin
  location: class Problem
Problem.java:24: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: You need to include `" "` in `split()`, it should be `split(" ");` not `split();`

Comment: It's complaining about `stdin` missing. Where did you declare `stdin`? Can you post the entire code?